# Issue while switching rapidly between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

In a LinearLayout I have a FragmentContainer and below it is a RadioGroup containing several RadioButtons. When check changes i will replace the current fragment in container with the different fragment. Switching happens fine if the checking is done slowly.

**Now Consider** :
RadioButtonA => on checking replaces container with FragmentA
RadioButtonB => on checking replaces container with FragmentB

**Now container has FragmentA**
if i change to RadioButtonA->RadioButtonB it **Replaces FragmentA with FragmentB** and 

instantaneously if i switch from RadioButtonB->RadioButtonA **it SHOULD Replace FragmentB with FragmentA**

But I get exception saying:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: FragmentA

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine now. The problem was after replace the fragment i was setting the transition

```
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
```

What i assume is that the trasition(for FragmentA) would be still runningwhen i switched to FragmentB.

FragmentA is not removed from backstack till transition is finished. At this point if try to add the FragmentA again, it would crash because the FragmentA has not been removed yet

So dont set any Transition